# Hey I'm creating a coding exam platform and I want to restrict the user to open developer tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I'm trying to create a coding exam portal like hacker rank or the one at prepbytes.com but I cant find a way to restrict the user to not open any tabs and not open the developer tools ( right click + inspect element), I've seen few examinations websites do it. Can any one please help me out on how to do it, I'm using react JS to build the exam platform everything is done just have to fix these issues and one more thing that I want to know is that how many tabs/windows that a user has opened.

Comment: _"I cant find a way to restrict the user to not open any tabs and not open the developer tools"_ That's not possible. You can always open dev tools and new tabs. You can even start most browsers with a command line argument to open all new tabs and windows with open dev tools. _"how many tabs/windows that a user has opened"_ The only way to find this out is a browser extension.

Comment: For Chrome you can use `chrome.exe --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

Comment: It is possible go to thinkexam.com or prepbytes.com and write an exam, I've written twice they'll open up a exam portal and no matter what you cannot access the developer tools, and there are websites that can easily track the no. Of tabs opened by the user, I dont think that you know anything about javascript.

Comment: You're not the first person here on Stack Overflow who told me that this is possible. And everytime someone sent a link with some special blocker, I opened the dev tools in less than a minute. The blockers don't work for developers. You just need to know your tools. You can set a breakpoint on page load. You can initially open dev tools in a floating window. If you don't know how to open dev tools, it doesn't mean it's not possible.

Comment: You can load the website first in your browser, copy the whole request and use a headless browser to access and modify everything you want in the website.

Comment: Can you provide links to websites that block dev tools or count the number of tabs and are accessible without registration?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only can handle the keyboard event (CTRL + Shift + I -> On windows) to prevent default and not open dev tools, but i dont think you can restrict accessing it from browser interface.